# Azure Media Player square aspect ratio videos fullscreen

Tags: javascript, css, azure, video, azure-media-services

Using AMP version 2.0.0, default skin.

I'm trying to play a 1:1 aspect ratio video from my media services account in Azure media player. Doing this using 800/500px width/height caused the video to extend well below the height of the modal window it is playing in. I fixed this issue by setting the height of the video to 500px and the width to auto (when non-fullscreen). This setting works for both 16:9 and 1:1 aspect ratio (it's not ideal, but it does work).

When I fullscreen the video, the width and height are set to 100%, and so half of the video is lost. I would like the video to play with height max and black letterboxing at the sides, as it does in WMP. If I could get the same effect when playing in non-fullscreen that would also be good. If I set the video height to anything other than 100% when the player is fullscreen it just moves the playbar up the screen rather than resizing the video. Anyone have any advice on how to get this working?

As a last resort I would also accept not being able to set the video to fullscreen, but I can't find documentation on how to do that either.

[image: nonfullscreen]

[image: fullscreen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue here was a rogue css rule setting the height of all s to 100%